# setTimeout and promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, settimeout

I need to fetch data, and it could take some time. If it takes more than 100ms I want to show a loader. This is what I did

```
fetchOptions(value, page = 0){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });
}

getOptions(text, page = 0) {
    if (this.requestTimeout) clearTimeout(this.requestTimeout);
    this.requestTimeout = setTimeout((()=>{
      console.log("!!");
    }), 100);

this.fetchOptions(text, page)
      .then(data => {
        //do something
        //if (this.requestTimeout) clearTimeout(this.requestTimeout);
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
 }
```

`fetchOptions` works for 5 seconds cause it contains a function like

```
sleep(ms) {
    var unixtime_ms = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < unixtime_ms + ms) {}
}
```

(because I wanted to test long fetching process).

As a result `console.log` is called only after promise resolved. I really need a help to understand why does it happen and how to solve this problem

Comment: `while(new Date().getTime() < unixtime_ms + ms) {}` blocks the program, your timers, the user, and basically everything else on your website. Don't do it.

Comment: @tcooc is right. You better use a promise with a resolve in a timeout for the sleep method.
Like this: sleep (ms) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(resolve, 5000); }) }

Comment: Thank you guys, it does make sense. Feeling myself really stupid now :)

Answer (score 0):

Is CSS an option? You can set a class immediately and use animations to delay the effect.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('effect'),
  false);
```

```css
.effect { 
  background-color:red; 
  animation: effect 500ms forwards;
  border:1px solid black;
  }

@keyframes effect {
    0% {background-color:transparent;}
    99% { background-color:transparent; }
    100% {background-color:red;}
}
```

```html
<button type='button'>Toggle Class</button>
<div>result</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid it would be a big headache in my particular case, but it's a really beautiful idea!